# Rails model associations, has_many :through and has_one with the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have two models: User and State. The state model has records for each of the 50 states in the United States.

I would like each User to have two attributes: one "home" state, and many states to "visit".

I know I have to set up some sort of model associations to achieve this, but not sure what the best approach is.

Here's what I have so far, but I know there must be something wrong with have has_many and has_one association to the same model.

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :visits
   has_many :states, :through => :visits
   has_one :state
end

#visit.rb
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :state
end

#state.rb
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
   has many :visits
   has many :users, :through => :visits 
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion what you already have is almost right, except you would store the home state foreign key on the user like thus:

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :visits
  has_many :states, through: visits
end

# visit.rb
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :state
end

# state.rb
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :visits
  has_many :users, through: :visits
end
```

You would then access the home state like thus:

```
u = User.first
u.state
```

And the visited states, like thus:

```
u = User.first
u.states
```

For programming clarity, you can rename your relations:

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_state, class_name: "State"
  has_many :visits
  has_many :visited_states, class_name: "State", through: visits
end

# state.rb
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :residents, class_name: "User"
  has_many :visits
  has_many :visitors, class_name: "User", through: :visits
end
```

Your domain model would make more sense:

```
u = User.first
u.home_state
u.visited_states

s = State.first
s.residents
s.visitors
```

I expect you'll probably want to store additional information about the visit, so keeping the HMT join table for the `Visit` model will allow you to do this, rather than going with a HABTM relation. You could then add attributes to the visit:

```
# xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_create_visits.rb
class CreateVisits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :visits do |t|
      t.text :agenda
      t.datetime commenced_at
      t.datetime concluded_at
      t.references :state
      t.references :user
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a has_many and has_one relationship on a single model, in this case state. One solution is to:

create a static model of states, they do not need to be a database model, they could be a static variable on the state model: `US_STATES = {'1' => 'AK', '2' => 'AL', etc}` or you could use fixtures to load a table of states into the database (more complicated because you need to use a rake task or the db:seed task to load the fixtures into the db, but nice because you can use active record to manage the model).

then you can provide a home_state_id on the user model that defines the home_state and the visits are simply a join between user_id and the state_id.

Comment: PS. you inspired me to write this up into a post I've been meaning to do for a long time: http://jedschneider.posterous.com/using-semi-static-data-as-an-activerecord-mod

Comment: Thanks! So essentially, I can remove the has_one relationship, and instead have a table column called :home_state in the User model which references a :state_id from the State static model? Should I keep the has_many :through relationship for the visits?

Comment: Oh cool, just saw the link to your new post. I'm totally a newbie to Rails, so will try to apply what you wrote in your post to my home state and states to visit problem!

Comment: if you go the static list route, to clarify you would create a module, like so: http://rolandmai.com/%3Fp%3D100 that would probably live in /lib/us_state.rb and then you would include the module in any model that needed to know about states. 
  class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    include US_State
  end

Comment: If I use a static list, would I still be able to use `has_many :states, :through => :visits`?

Comment: You can have as many `has_many/has_one` association as you wish, as long as they are named differently and they represent different concepts. Example: a user in a forum has many created threads (inverse of Thread.created_by) and also many subscribed threads (through Subscription intermediate model)

Comment: @rewritten, upvoted your response because you are correct about no limit on relations provided they represent different concepts, just think the `Thread` example is a bad one considering Thread is an existing Ruby class. Calling `created_by` on Thread would result in a no method exception.

Comment: LOL @Dom you are right! I didn't think about that... Of course never name your own classes like this. Anyway TDD would have catched that very soon!

Answer (score 1):

> I would like each User to have two attributes: one "home" state, and many states to "visit".

In your models, a state may only be home to one user (`belongs_to`).

The correct semantics would be

```
class User < AR::Base
  belongs_to :home_state, :class_name => "State", :foreign_key => "home_state_id", :inverse_of => :users_living
  has_and_belongs_to_many :visited_states, :through => :visits
  # ...
end

class State < AR::Base
  has_many :users_living, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :home_state
  # ...
end
```