# Rails: has_many through between two models and also a has_many/belongs to on the same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a has many through relationship to define the questions that a user has answered.

How do to setup a relationship for the questions that a user has created?

Normally you would just create a has_many and belongs_to relationship between users and questions, but since I am also doing a has_many through this will not work.

Here is what I have so far:

Models:

```
Users
Questions
Answered_questions
```

User model

```
has_many :answered_questions
has_many :questions, :through => :answered_questions
```

Question model:

```
has_many :answered_questions
has_many :users, :through => :answered_questions
```

Answered_questions model

```
belongs_to :question
belongs_to :user
```

**EDIT**

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637532/756623, which led me to try this:

User model addition:

```
has_many :questions_created, :class_name => "Question", :inverse_of => :created_by
```

Question model addition:

```
belongs_to :created_by, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "created_by_id", :inverse_of => :questions_created
```

I also added the column `created_by_id` to the Questions table

Now...the `user_id` is not being added to the `created_by_id` column.

What do I have wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to add the `created_by_id`?

Comment: I think that may be my problem....I don't know how to add the created_by_id...

Comment: The `created_by_id` will be added while the question is being created. So in your controller you can try something like `@question = current_user.questions_created.new(params[:question])` and then save it by `@question.save`. Or whatever logic are you using, you just need to call the question by `user_instance.created_question_association`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this may solve your problem:

```
# User
has_many :answered_questions
has_many :questions, :through => :answered_questions
has_many :created_questions, class_name: Question, foreign_key: :author_id

# Question
has_many :answered_questions
has_many :users, :through => :answered_questions
belongs_to :author, class_name: User

# Answered questions
belongs_to :question
belongs_to :user
```

Comment: author_id is much better then created_by_id...but I am still getting nil for the "author_id" field